# Setting default storage location in 4.0.4?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sd-card, installation, storage

My sister got a tablet for Christmas which runs 4.0.4. The internal storage is measly, but she has a big enough SD card.

Going to Settings > Storage *should* give the option to set the 'Default storage location' to either internal storage or external SD card, but it doesn't. My phone (which runs the exact same firmware version) *does* have the option to do it.

What ways can I change the default storage location for Android 4.0.4? We're at our wits' end here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Joshua: Can I ask you what brand and model is her tablet?

Answer (score 1):

If the "DEFAULT STORAGE" is not showing there then you should use any third party application. App2sd,AndroidAssistant, CleanMaster or Link2SD should do this. But if your device is rooted you should definitely try Link2SD, with some few tweaks it automatically transfers all apps to sdcard. Hope that helps.